# How do I output translated text strings on edit screens

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, localization

I want to output a localized text string above the post/page listing table (edit.php). Everything seems to work except that the string will only be in English (original string, not the translated one).

I have all my code in a plugin and all other strings are being translated as expected (po and mo files are working). I have tried to move the string around and tried to change `load-edit.php` action to others that fire later such as `admin_head`, `adminmenu` and `admin_notices` but it doesn't seem to matter.

Does anyone know what I'm getting wrong?

#### Excerpt from the plugin:

```
define('MY_TEXTDOMAIN', 'my-plugin');

function myplugin_load_textdomain() {
    load_plugin_textdomain( MY_TEXTDOMAIN, false, dirname( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) ) . '/languages' ); 
}
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'myplugin_load_textdomain' );

// Add submenu page under "Pages"
function my_patterns_admin_menu() {
    add_submenu_page( 
        'edit.php?post_type=page', 
        _x('Patterns', 'page title', MY_TEXTDOMAIN), 
        _x('Patterns','menu title', MY_TEXTDOMAIN), 
        'edit_posts', 
        'edit.php?post_type=wp_block', 
        '');
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_patterns_admin_menu' );

// Add text to edit screens. Called only in /wp-admin/edit.php pages
add_action( 'load-edit.php', function() {
    add_filter( 'views_edit-wp_block', 'patterns_info' );
});

// Content output above table
function patterns_info() {
    $rb_desc = _x('My text in english','description', MY_TEXTDOMAIN);
    echo '<span style="display:block;margin: 1rem 0;border-left: 4px solid #888;padding: 8px 16px;background: #fff;">'. $rb_desc .'</span>';
}
```

**Output:** *My text in english*

**Desirable output:** *Min text på svenska* (*My text in English* translated to Swedish, which is present in the po/mo files)

Comment: How are you generating the language files? Note that the text domain should not be a variable or constant, because most tools that parse your code to generate language files do not actually execute the code, and variables etc. will not be populated.

Comment: In this case with poEdit and it works great. I have ~100 strings translated and everyone of them works except the above. :) Yeah, I've always written textdomain as __('Hello', 'my-textdomain') before but saw some examples where they were using a constant so I decided to try it out. I have changed the constant to 'my-plugin' instead but there's no difference (but thank you for the tip Jacob, I will change this in all my projects)